# Custom Theme Single Product Page Wordpress/Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am building my custom theme and my single.php displays woocommerce single product page with

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) {
          the_post();
          the_content();
    }
}
```

[image]

Why is the page missing - title, reviews & breadcrumbs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
        add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
    add_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
    }
    
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```

Please add this one in the functions.php file

Answer (score 1):

Woocommerce has its own templates for their pages. A single product should be showing on single-product.php. You would create a woocommerce folder inside your custom theme and copy the directories and files you want to edit over to your theme.

**How to override single-product.php**

If you want to custimize the single-product.php, you would create a woocommerce folder in your theme and copy the single-product.php over into it. So the directory would be `yourtheme/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php`. This way you have all the actions hooking in the functionality you are missing.

Here are the docs:
https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Answer (score 0):

I was missing

```
add_theme_support('woocommerce');
```

in my functions.php file